# How to add percent done by story count to cardboard

Tags: rally

I am struggling to incorporate the percent done by story count into a kanban board I have built (kanban of portfolio items.)  I was tried working off of:

https://github.com/RallyApps/PortfolioKanban

but I could not quite figure out how to incorporate the percent done by story count aspect.  Anyone know of a simple way to add this to each of the cards?

Answer (score 0):

There are two paces in the PortfolioKanbanApp.js where PercentDoneByStoryCount is referenced:

```
 config: {
            defaultSettings: {
                fields: 'PercentDoneByStoryCount'
            }
        },
```

and

```
_attachPercentDoneToolTip:function (cardboard) {
            Ext.create('Rally.ui.tooltip.PercentDoneToolTip', {
                target:cardboard.getEl(),
                delegate:'.percentDoneContainer',
                percentDoneName: 'PercentDoneByStoryCount',
            //...
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Nick. I get a GET https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/panel/Rally/ui/tooltip/PercentDoneToolTip.js?_dc=1375373102475 404 (Not Found)

Comment: The code isn't entirely compatible with 2.0rc1. If you change to 2.0p5 the error should go away.
<script type="text/javascript" src="/apps/2.0p5/sdk.js"></script> 
Also, if you do not plan to customize this app, it is better to install it directly from the App Catalog when you create your custom page in Rally. When you crate a new page, click on "Start adding apps" and navigate to Portfolio/Program Management Apps in the catalog.
In the documentation https://prod.help.rallydev.com/portfolio-kanban-board-app it is stated that Source code is not available for this app.

Comment: I am adding this to a complete custom app, and I just wanted to have the tool tip on the cards in my cardboard.  And there are other parts of my app that won't work on 2.0p5, but will work on 2.0rc1 :(

Comment: the app was originally written for 2.0p3. The entire app works with 2.0p3 and I tested it with 2.0p5 and it worked as well.

Comment: But I am not using the app as written.  I am trying to add this feature to my own app - which involves a kanban board of portfolio items, which is now supported just using the normal cardboard with the proper model.  There are other parts of my app that rely on 2.0rc1, so I cannot simply revert.  I am wondering if there is a custom solution, not an entire app, that would work for 2.0rc1

Comment: I looked for it yesterday when I noticed a problem while using rc1, but unfortunately did not find it.

Comment: Thank you for your help and for looking into that!

Comment: I am also struggling to add the PercentDoneToolTip to a custom cardboard app in 2.0rc1. Did you find a solution?